# convert integer to double in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment, type-conversion

I have encountered this problem in R
I have one value which is of type Integer

```
typeof(res[3,"V2.review/score"])
[1] "integer"
```

And I want to assign this value to a Double column

```
typeof(HLPMatrix[1,1])
[1] "double"
```

The value in

```
res[3,"V2.review/score"]
[1]  4.0
```

But when I use assignment

```
HLPMatrix[1,1]<-res[3,"V2.review/score"]
HLPMatrix[1,1]
[1] 122
```

HLPMatrix[1,1] gets value 122

Is there any solution to this
I tried as.double and as.numeric options but that also returns the same value
I want Assignment of value 4.0 to this HLPMatrix[1,1]

Comment: Got the solution
as.double(as.character(res[3,"V2.review/score"]))

Comment: If you've found a solution, you should post it as an answer and accept it.

Comment: I forgot to tick the option answering the question myself.

Comment: Just click the blue "Answer your question" button...

Answer (score 0):

It just happened to me today.

Use:

```
 Variable1<-as.double(as.character(Variable))
```